# Swift - get kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason from CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to understand why my AVCaptureOutput is dropping frames. In the `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` delegate method, I get a `CMSampleBuffer` that should contains an attachement explaining the reason the frame was dropped ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1388468-captureoutput))

The reason is expected to be one of those CFString:

```
kCMSampleBufferDroppedFrameReason_FrameWasLate // "FrameWasLate"
kCMSampleBufferDroppedFrameReason_OutOfBuffers // "OutOfBuffers"
kCMSampleBufferDroppedFrameReason_Discontinuity // "Discontinuity"
```

From the docs it's really not clear how to get this value. I've tried using `CMGetAttachment` but this returns a `CMAttachmentMode` aka `UInt32`:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
  var reason: CMAttachmentMode = 0
  CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason, &reason)
  print("reason \(reason)") // 1
}
```

and I don't really know how to match this UInt32 to the CFString constant

Answer (score 9):

I was stupidly not looking at the right output:

```
var mode: CMAttachmentMode = 0
let reason = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason, &mode)
print("reason \(String(describing: reason))") // Optional(OutOfBuffers)
```